# Exception when running WCF service on Ubuntu by Mono

Tags: wcf, exception, mono

there

**Runtime Context:** I write a simple WCF console application by VS2012,running smoothly on Windows, but exception happened when try to run it on Ubuntu by mono

**Mono Version**: 2.10.6

**Exception:**

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: None of the listener channel types is supported
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.BuildListener (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint se, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection pl) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.BuildChannelDispatcher (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint se, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection commonParams) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen (TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open (TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open () [0x00000] in :0 
  at DynIPServiceHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

The Only Main function is :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {     
        try
        {
            Binding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(DynIPService.DynIPService));
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint("DynIPServiceContract.IDynIPService", binding, "net.tcp://10.161.66.213:808");
            sh.Open();
            foreach (var ep in sh.Description.Endpoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}, ListenUri: {1}, ListenUriMode: {2} ", ep.Address, ep.ListenUri, ep.ListenUriMode);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
            //Console.WriteLine("Current Uri is:);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us the configuration?

Comment: Hi, Thorsten, I dont' use app.config for service, what configuration should be show, I guess it is the mono version issue, i remember that I run a WCF demo at home 's ubuntu machine, there is no this exception,  that mono version is 2.10.8 but not 2.10.6, any way, i will test it when back to home later on. Thanks so much..

Comment: I confirm it does a Mono version issue, In my home machine, the mono version is 2.10.8.1, and there is no problem as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't have anything that old, but it's working fine for me with 2.10.9 (the oldest version that I have on my machine) and newer.